# Access $rootScope value in Kendo Grid for export to excel dynamic file name

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, angularjs-rootscope

[image]        This is HTML
        ------------

```
                                        <div class="lm-panel panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="lm-panel-heading dragHandle panel-heading">
                                                <span ng-style="styleCtrl.style15(styleCtrl.fontFace,styleCtrl.fontSize)">
                                                    <b>
                                                       **{{figure.caption}}**
                                                    </b>
                                                </span>
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    This is controller=>
    ---------------------- 
    columns: vm.columnsList,
                    excel: {
                        fileName: $scope.figure.caption + ".xlsx",
                        allPages: true,
                        filterable: true
```

### },

So when I first export to excel, then file name is correct. But If we change parameter, then Our Caption changed but if we export to excel, Then file name remains same as before. Please help me how to do it.

Comment: Hi, this is limitation of Kendo UI Grid that we can not give updated file name on every clik of exprt to excel, For this we have to make a saperate function.

Comment: My guess is that Kendo Grid doesn't re-evaluate the filename for each save operation. You mentioned making a separate function, care to demonstrate that here as an answer to the question?